# liveCycle force close document

Tags: javascript, adobe, livecycle-designer

I was tasked to create a function to "protect" document with a password.
I figured and the previous forms create a dialog asking for a password then validate it with the value in an hidden field on the form if they are not the same close the pdf file, I know this is not the most secure way to protect but the user is well aware of it and is fine with it "unless i can find a way to to automate the securing of the file.

My issue now is that i can't seems to be able to execute javascript code that would close the form "in liveCycle" because of security restriction implemented by adobe from what i understand.

I know that with acrobat pro i can use he command this.closeDoc(); to do this but everything i tried with live cycle (different version of app.execMenuItem("close"); &
event.target.closeDoc(true); ) has failed to work. Any idea how i could force the security to allow one of those two command or to use another command to close the document programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: Seems like the only way to make it work is to close the document from another "event" than initialize.
Using app.execMenuItem("Close"); in the form.docRead event make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this -

```
app.setTimeOut('this.closeDoc(true);', 1);
```

It worked for me for one of my requirements in the button 'click' event.